# how to subclass a subclass of a UIViewController

Tags: uiviewcontroller, subclass

I'm stumped! This should be so simple...

I create a subclass of UIViewController (call it alphaVC class). This will have several 'generic' methods.
But when I try to create a subclass of alphaVC (call it betaVC, with specific methods), alphaVC is not recognized under New File/Objective C class/Subclass of...
if I manually create the .h with [ @interface betaVC : alphaVC ] it won't compile, complaining that there is no such class as alphaVC.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry all.

I rebuilt the .h file manually and all seems to be working OK. Either sun-spots or a brain fart was the problem.

Still can't see alphaVC in New File/Objective C class/Subclass of... dropdown.